# Sybase ASE and functions parameters?

Tags: sql, t-sql, function, sap-ase

Is it possible to create a function that might be called with a different number of parameters (minimum two).

So, two parameters are always present and the others are optional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try default parameter, like this:

```
create function your_func (@p1 int, @p2 int, @p3 int = 123, @p4 int = 456)
```

I am not sure about Sybase ASE, but this would work on MS SQL Server's T-SQL.